# Usage of LU decomposition over UL decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

What are some advantages of using LU decomposition over UL decomposition? From what I see, they can both be used equally well to solve $MX=V$ through forward and backward substitution, and since the determinant is commutative for triangular matricies, they can both be used. Some googling returns nothing on the UL decomposition, leading me to believe that LU has some advantages over UL. So why is LU decomposition preferred?

Source: Linear Algebra by Cherney, Denton, Waldron

Comment: Convention, I suppose?

Comment: I'd say something like that, and I guess with time passing, people just "forgot" about UL. I don't see any technical difference between the two.

Comment: With column oriented storage UL variant is much less efficient than LU.

Comment: @PawelKowal Can you expand on this comment? I'm still a little confused.

Answer (score -1):

In an otherwise banded matrix, sparseness is preserved by:
(1) LU decomposition when there are full rows at the bottom and/or
columns on the right;
(2) UL decomposition when there are full rows at the top and/or columns on
the left.